# Is there any way to reduce standard second-order logic to first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

By saying "standard second-order logic" I am specifically ruling out Henkin semantics.   It is my understanding that the approach generally taken is to map the second-order syntax to first-order syntax and second-order semantics to first-order semantics.   Specifically, I would like to know the formal and rigorous definition of "reduction".  I have developed a proof that standard second-order logic can be reduced to first-order logic and I have heard that this contradicts existing impossibility results.  I think the contradiction results from me not knowing the formal definition of "reduction".  The definition I am using is that every proof in standard second-order logic uniquely maps a proof in first-order logic such that the original standard second-order syntax and semantics is derivable from the resulting proof.   The mapping is injective meaning for every standard second-order proof there exists one first-order proof but not all first order proofs have a corresponding second-order proof.

I have heard some claim that the definition of "reduction" is elementary equivalence.   I know that elementary equivalence would be sufficient to show that standard second-order logic cannot be reduced to first-order logic using the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem (LST), however, this proof seems to rely on the requirement that standard second-order semantics maps directly to first-order semantics.  Have mathematicians considered the possibility of instead mapping standard second-order semantics to first-order syntax?  If so, does this make "reduction" possible and what are the drawbacks of such an approach as compared with mapping syntax to syntax and semantics to semantics?

Furthermore, when the reduction is performed, this implies second-order logic becomes complete and consistent.  For example, when I reduce the halting problem I get a contradiction, which implies one of the axioms of the standard second-order logic proof is false.  In addition, I can prove (in first-order logic) that the false axiom must be the Axiom of Infinity, because when this axiom is corrected by replacing N with a finite subset of N the result is that there is no contradiction and the halting problem becomes decidable.

Comment: What is a "proof in standard second-order logic"?

Comment: A "proof" would consist of a list of second-order sentences using the full syntax and semantics of second-order logic.  My reduction method is so general that admits any definition of "proof" that you want to use.  Yes, there is no formal proof calculus, but this cannot stop us from reducing proofs that are effectively checkable (regardless of whether they are sound or complete).

Comment: Almost everything here is extremely unclear to me. "Have mathematicians considered the possibility of instead mapping standard second-order semantics to first-order syntax?" I don't know what this means. "when I reduce the halting problem" The halting problem isn't a sentence or a proof; so, what does it mean to reduce it? "I get a contradiction" And why doesn't that tell you instead that there is an issue with your claimed proof, rather than that one of the axioms of set theory must be false?

Comment: This would all be a lot easier to work with if you clarified what you mean when you say "I have developed a proof that standard second-order logic can be reduced to first-order logic" - what do **you** mean by "reduce" in this case? What sort of thing is the reduction whose existence you claim?

Comment: I did give my definition of reduction in the details. "The definition I am using is that every proof in standard second-order logic uniquely maps a proof in first-order logic such that the original standard second-order syntax and semantics is derivable from the resulting proof. The mapping is injective meaning for every standard second-order proof there exists one first-order proof but not all first order proofs have a corresponding second-order proof." Now, I can actually extend "second-order proof" to any effective calculus with syntax and semantics.

Comment: @JohnJenkins But you haven't actually defined "second-order proof," and your response to Alex doesn't clear things up at all. Also I have no idea what "the original standard second-order syntax and semantics is derivable from the resulting proof" or "I can actually extend "second-order proof" to any effective calculus with syntax and semantics" means.

Comment: I just did in my last comment.  My method applies to any effective calculus.  There are many ways to define effective second-order logic, all of those ways are covered by my reduction method.

Comment: "My reduction method is so general that admits any definition of "proof" that you want to use. Yes, there is no formal proof calculus, but this cannot stop us from reducing proofs that are effectively checkable" It sounds like what you're actually describing is a procedure for reducing arbitrary "effective fragments" of second-order logic to first-order logic; that's a very different thing entirely than reducing the whole logic at once.

Comment: (Also FYI if you want me to see a comment, put "@NoahSchweber" in it.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, except that it is possible to write entire effective proofs in second-order logic and many such proofs exist.   Generally, it is hard for a mathematician to consider something a "proof" if it is not effectively checkable.

Comment: OK, but then you're not talking about a reduction of standard second-order logic to first-order logic, you're talking about a *system of* reductions of *fragments of* standard second-order logic to first-order logic. And, again, that's a very different animal.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you give an example of proof in standard second-order logic that is not effectively checkable?  It is my understanding that standard second-order logic is effective.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: "It is my understanding that standard second-order logic is effective. Is this incorrect?" **Yes, that is incorrect**. Moreover, there isn't even such a thing as a "second-order proof" in the standard semantics in the first place, hence Alex's and my focus on this issue.

Comment: To get a sense of just how bad second-order logic with the standard semantics is, consider the problem of telling whether a single second-order sentence is a validity (= true in every model according to the standard semantics; ideally, this would correspond to "provable"). In first-order logic, this set is computably enumerable. In second-order logic, it's not even [hyperarithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory). In fact, it's not even set-theoretically well-behaved: there is a second-order sentence which is valid iff the continuum hypothesis is true. *It's terrible*.

Comment: Yes, but this is a matter of sentence validity.  To get around this I admit all sentences, whether they are valid or not.  What I am referring to is effective inference rules.   You seem to be implying that because I cannot check the validity of a statement I cannot have effective inference rules.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you give an example of an inference in second-order logic that is not effectively checkable?  You said "Yes, this is incorrect." in bold but you gave no counterexample.

Comment: @JohnJenkins We can write a single sentence $\theta$ in second-order logic in the language of arithmetic which characterizes the standard model of arithmetic up to isomorphism. This means that for each first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic, $\theta\rightarrow\varphi$ is a validity iff $\varphi$ is true in the standard model of arithmetic. So there's no way of effectively checking whether a second-order sentence is entailed by $\emptyset$, since that would imply that true first-order arithmetic is r.e.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, well then can you give such a sentence and an actual inference that I could not effectively check?  If you can do it in your brain then I can do it on a Turing machine.  Yes, that does result in a contradiction (in first-order logic), establishing the fallacy of completed infinite sets.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Either the continuum hypothesis is true or it isn't. Which is it? This is equivalent to a question about second-order validity: I can write down a sentence $\varphi$ which is a validity iff CH holds, and I can write down a sentence $\psi$ which is a validity iff CH fails. Either $\emptyset\models_2\varphi$ or $\emptyset\models_2\psi$ is a correct inference, but we have no process for telling which.

Comment: Based on your other question, though, you seem to have a very different notion of "inference" in mind. Until you precisely define that, though, none of these questions are answerable. (And I think now I've hit the point of diminishing returns, barring a precise definition on your part of "inference" here.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe this would help? https://www.quora.com/Can-you-check-a-second-order-logic-proof-with-a-Turing-machine/answer/David-R-Jefferson

Comment: @JohnJenkins That's talking about *a fixed effective proof system* (and the answerer doesn't mention that there are lots of nonequivalent such systems, so at that level it's ambiguous), but you're talking about *the full semantics*, and such proof systems are not complete for that semantics. **Choose one**: either you're talking about a fixed effective deduction system, in which case the result is reducible to first-order logic *but nobody claims otherwise*, or you're talking about the full semantics, in which case the corresponding inference notion is not in fact effective.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have always been talking about a fixed deductive system.  How else can you reduce logic?  No wonder this conversation was so confusing.

Comment: @JohnJenkins But you've **also** always, from the very top, emphasized that you're using the full semantics - which isn't compatible with that. If you're fixing a specific system, say that, and don't bother mentioning the standard semantics since it's irrelevant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I choose a fixed specific system from all possible systems, then reduce the proof.  I have been saying this from the beginning.

Comment: Then why have you kept talking about - from the beginning - the standard semantics? It's literally the title and first sentence of your question. Do you understand why these things are completely unrelated?

Comment: @NoahSchweber They are not unrelated.  Again, I choose a fixed effective proof in an effective deductive system with full syntax and semantics.  They are not completely unrelated at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If the deductive system does not admit proof then there is no effective proof, so "reduction" has no meaning.  I cannot reduce nothing.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Deductive systems don't have semantics - they either are or are not sound, and either are or are not complete, with respect to different semantics. And any fixed effective deduction system for second-order logic is not complete for the full semantics.

Comment: @JohnJenkins "If the deductive system does not admit proof then there is no effective proof, so "reduction" has no meaning." And again you're conflating multiple things - people simply don't use these terms in as narrow a way as you're using them. We can talk about non-effective deduction systems, or general deduction relations (or entailment relations) of arbitrary complexity, and reductions between these - my answer below does so to a certain extent. You're just mixing too many presuppositions at once, and that's why you're drawing contradictory conclusions. I give up.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "Deductive systems don't have semantics..." This is incorrect.  I am not sure where you got that.  Yes, soundness and completeness are separate issues, as I have said from the beginning.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, we can talk about non-effective deductive systems but that is all we can do.  By definition it is impossible to have a proof in a non-effective deduction system.  Why would you think it possible to reduce something that is not a proof to something that is a proof?   Non-effective deduction systems are just handwaving about what we think would nice.  When you conflate proof with intuition you are simply asking for fallacies and false results.

Comment: @NoahSchweber We might as well map all such non-effective "proofs" to true (or perhaps, more appropriately, false).

Comment: @NoshSchweber Indeed, as I said earlier, if you map such a non-effective "proof" (under the same mapping as the effective proofs) you get a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

The real inescapable obstacle isn't Lowenheim-Skolem, it's **compactness**. This prevents any reasonable notion of reduction I can think of, looking purely at how logical implication works within the syntax itself.

---

The term "reduction" is used in different ways depending on the context. I think the most general one, though, is the following.

First, we'll use a very permissive notion of "logic" - simply be a pair $\mathcal{L}=(S, \triangleright)$ where $S$ is a class of things we call *sentences* and $\triangleright$ is a relation between sets of sentences we call the *entailment relation*. There is no inherent semantics here, nor are there restrictions on how complicated either piece can be; however, intuitively "$A\triangleright B$" means "Every model of $A$ is also a model of $B$" (that is, identify $\triangleright$ with $\models$).

The simplest notion of reduction, then, is just a map on sentences which preserves and reflects the entailment relation: given logics $\mathcal{L}_0=(S_0,\triangleright_0)$ and $\mathcal{L}_1=(S_1,\triangleright_1)$, a *reduction from $\mathcal{L}_0$ to $\mathcal{L}_1$* is a map $f:S_0\rightarrow S_1$ such that for each $A, B\subseteq S_0$ we have $$A\triangleright_0B\quad\iff\quad f[A]\triangleright_1 f[B]$$ (where "$g[X]$" denotes $\{g(x): x\in X\}$).

**Note that we're not saying anything about how complicated $f$ can be - any old map will do.**

---

For concreteness I'll write $\mathcal{L}_1=(S_1,\models_1)$ and $\mathcal{L}_2=(S_2,\models_2)$ for first- and second-order logic, respectively.

The point is that [$\mathcal{L}_1$ is compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem): if $\Gamma\models_1\varphi$ for $\Gamma\subseteq S_1,\varphi\in S_1$, then we have $\Gamma_0\models_1\varphi$ for some finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq S_1$. However, $\mathcal{L}_2$ is *not* compact. A counterexample is easy enough to whip up - for example, consider - in the language of PA together with a new constant symbol $c$ - the set $\Gamma$ consisting of the usual system of *second-order* Peano arithmetic (so the "full" induction principle) together with for each $n$ an axiom saying that $c\ge n$. According to the standard semantics we have $\Gamma\models_2 \perp$ (put another way: $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable), but no finite subset of $\Gamma$ has this property.

But this rules out the possibility of a reduction from second-order logic to first-order logic. Suppose $f$ were a reduction of $\mathcal{L}_2$ to $\mathcal{L}_1$. Then we have $f[\Gamma]\models_1f(\perp)$. But then by compactness of $\mathcal{L}_1$ we would have $A\models_1f(\perp)$ for some finite $A\subseteq f[\Gamma]$. This $A$ in turn is just $f[\Gamma_0]$ for some finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq \Gamma$, so we must have $$\Gamma_0\models_2\perp$$ since $f[\Gamma_0]\models_1f(\perp)$, and this doesn't occur.

More generally, **no non-compact logic can ever be reduced to a compact logic**.

Comment: Yes, I addressed something similar to this in my details, namely, the halting problem (and, by that, I meant the undecidability proof thereof).  When it reduces you get a contradiction.  This contradiction demonstrates that all infinite second-order logic relies on a false axiom, namely, the Axiom of Infinity.   The reduction works fine as long as your $\Gamma$ is a finite set, which proves that it must be the Axiom of Infinity leading to the contradiction.   In other words, my reduction method establishes that all effective calculi are either inconsistent or finite.

Comment: And, let me by clear, when I say it proves this, I mean it rigorous and formally proves it because we already know that first-order logic is complete and consistent.  So if a contradiction is reached it must be that one of the axioms was false.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Or that your argument is incorrect. Without seeing your argument in detail of course I can't say anything specific, but with all due respect that is certainly my guess.

Comment: Essentially, my argument relies on the construction of a Turing machine in first-order logic.  By definition, all effective calculi can be implemented on a Turing machine.  I take the syntax and semantics symbol by symbol and form sentences of the form conjuntions of predicates P(<symbol>,<line>,<column>).  I then encode all of the effective inference rules of second-order logic into the Turing machine.   Then, it is clear that if a proof is effectively checkable in second-order logic its reduced form is also effectively checkable first-order logic.

Comment: I include one additional rule that says if I have a line of the form $  P('\sim',line,0) \wedge P('(',line,1) \wedge ... \wedge  P(')',line, n)$ it is equivalent to:  $  \sim (P('(',line,0) \wedge ... \wedge  P(')',line, n-1))$. This ensures that contradictions are preserved.

Comment: Any comment here?   Did you follow the above rough outline of my proof?

Comment: @JohnJenkins Honestly, I can't follow any of that. Too much is left completely unclear - in particular, "I then encode all of the effective inference rules of second-order logic into the Turing machine" is hiding a *ton*. My guess is that when you actually unwind this you're secretly claiming to be able to effectively tell whether a proposed effective deductive system is in fact sound for the standard semantics, which you can't do. But comments here aren't a good place to hash this out.

Comment: Can we start a discussion?  (I do not know how to do that and I am not sure if I have enough points or badges to start one, so you would have to start it.) In short, what I have established is that second-order logic with full semantics can be done in first-order logic simply by the fact that no process a human can perform is beyond the capability of a Turing machine.